# A question from Titchmarsh's Riemann Zeta Function textbook.

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have one query, concerning the newest edition of this monograph.

1. At page 7, section 1.2, at the bottom of the page, it's written that:
   " It is easily seen that $\zeta(s)=2$ for $s=\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a real number greater than 1..."

I am quite sure that for $\alpha=2$ which is real and greater than 1, $
\zeta(s)=\frac{\pi^2}{6} \neq 2$, what do you think did Titchamarsh meant here?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Irrelevant comment: I looked for Titchmarsh on Google Books, and they appear to have it filed under "Architecture > History > General"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will take a stab at this. I think he is saying that for some real number $s > 1$, 
$\zeta(s) = 2.$  We know that on the interval $(1,\infty)$ the $\zeta$ function is continuous and monotonically decreasing. Since $\zeta(t) \to \infty$ as $t \downarrow 1$
and $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6 < 2$, there must be some $s \in(1,2)$ with $\zeta(s) = 2.$

His writing somewhat obscures the existential nature of the statement he is making.

Comment: In short, T is saying $\zeta(\alpha)=2$ for *some* $\alpha$, not claiming $\zeta(\alpha)=2$ for *every* $\alpha$.

Comment: I wonder why T is cheap with words. Thanks.